# How to retrive data in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I am using post method.

Here is my `ts` file:

```
viewt(testid)
{
    $('#myModal22').modal('show');
    var param2 = {
        testid:testid,
    }
    this.service.get_tquestion(param2).subscribe(data => {
        this.test_question1 = data;
        console.log(data);
        console.log(this.test_question1);
    });
}
```

Also HTML Code:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let v of test_question1">
    <tr >
        <td>{{v.questionid}}</td>
        <td>{{v.questionname}}</td>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

And Service Part:

```
get_tquestion(param) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    // this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    return this.http.post(
        this.base_url + "test/getquestion", param, {headers: headers })
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

And API response is this:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Response what I am getting is:

> {"Code":200,"Results":[{"questionid":1034,"questionname":"Identify the adjective in the following sentence. We carried a few sandwiches for lunch.(Hard)","duration":60}]}

But I cannot display in HTML.

Comment: `test_question1` is not  an array. That's why you are getting this error.. Can you console log that and add to the question.?

Answer (score 3):

You're passing whole response from the API to `test_question1` variable. Since response is an object and it's not Iterable you cannot use it with `ngFor` directive. To fix this you can for example return data array from the service:

```
return this.http.post(this.base_url + "test/getquestion", param, { headers: headers })
    .map((res: Response) => res.json().Results);}
```

or assign property of response object inside subscription:

```
this.test_question1 = data.Results;
```

Comment: M getting:    res.json(...).Results is not a function

Comment: Why three dots inside `json()` method?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, works for me:

In your service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { URLSearchParams, Http, HttpModule, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
constructor(private http: Http) { }

authenticate(user_creds)
{
  //console.log(user_creds);
  const header = new Headers();
  header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  return this.http.post('http://localhost/valuesassessment/api/login/authenticate_login', user_creds, { headers: header })
    .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
}
```

In your `.ts` :

```
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    session_data: any = {};
constructor( private authService: AuthService ) 
{ 
  // your logic before init
}

authenticate(x)
{
    this.authService.authenticate(x)
                    .subscribe(data => 
                    {
                      if(data.ResponseCode == 411)
                      {
                        // console.log(data.ResponseCode)
                        this.session_data = data;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        this.session_data = data;
                        // console.log(this.session_data);
                      }
                    })
    this.session.store('header',this.header);
}
```

Note that before assigning responce to `session_data`, we have initialised it as type `any`.

Hope this helps.